# Ford Fiesta 06 diesel 1.4 new battery but car will only start if I bump start. What will cause this iv done a voltage output test on the alternator

Tags: ford, starting, fiesta

Iv got a Ford fiesta 06 diesel 1.4 tdci. My car would start with a jump or bump start so i purchased a new battery and my car would start no problem on that day but the next day my car wouldn't start and I had to go back and bump start. It has recently had a new clutch fitted. My headlights and dashboard are bright. Iv also done a voltage alternator and it shows that the battery is charging. So can you advise me what I need to replace.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What happens when it won't start? The lights are still bright? Do you hear any clicking at all when you turn the key?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Clean battery posts and terminals. They may look clean but may not be.
Step 2: Have parasitic draw test done.

You either have insufficient amps getting past your battery terminals, or something is draining the battery. A quick check on dirty posts is putting your voltmeter on the post. You should have 12.2 to 12.6 volts. Then put your meter to the cable terminals. You should get the same reading.